# How does an iPhone import photos from the photo stream?

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, photo-stream

If I put a picture on my Mac to photostream and it moves to my iPhone's photostream and I delete the picture from my photostream on my Mac, will there still be a picture left on the iPhone in the camera roll?

Answer (score 2):

### No.

When you delete an image from Photo Stream, there is a message (at least on iOS) that says something like

> The image will disappear from Photo Stream on all your devices.

Hence, deleted means no longer in Photo Stream *anywhere*.

Comment: The second part of this answer should be perhaps an explicit explanation that the iPhone doesn't import photos from the photo stream to the camera roll automatically. Since the OP isn't being detailed about the steps they take (and it's OK to not know the answer - that's why we ask questions) we can bring that point up explicitly.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. the photo remains on the camera roll, but deleted from the stream.

Comment: What action takes a photo from photo stream and places it into the camera roll? Is it a setting or a manual action you need to take?